# How to map in JPA a field that can hold a foreign key to on of two tables?

Tags: jpa

I have the following DB tables: Teacher and Student. They contain a few common fields I would like to hold in my java code in a Person class, which will be the parent class of my Teacher and Student entities. I also have an Event table, that contains an organizer field. The organizer field contains the id of either a Teacher or a Student.

The question is, can this be mapped in a way that the event contains a Person type as organizer? If not, what other options do I have?

Of course, there are plenty of solutions that require me to query the organizer separately from the event, I would like to avoid that.

Comment: That would be what is called table per class inheritance. There are many tutorials on how to use it, but the cons are many, so it should be discouraged as chances are better small changes to the schema might work better for you in the long run. Event for instance really cannot have a FK with a relational constraint; you have no way of knowing the value it holds actually references an existing row somewhere, or where it is, so integrity and querying become more complicated. Other options would be to map a Person table into the mix, as organizers can be more (or less) than the two choices.

Comment: @Chris what small changes do you suggest?

Comment: Add a person table with a person entity for the common elements for people. There are many alternatives to using table per class though

Comment: @Chris but then if I query for an Event, will the organizer be a Person type object or a Teacher/Student object?

Comment: What ever you want it to be. There are 3 types of inheritance with JPA entities - single table, joined table and table per class (the last is optional in the spec). Your Event will deal with Person which can then be a Student or Teacher instance (or a Person directly if they maybe are a volunteer?). With Joined inheritance, each student and Teacher will have a row in the Person table for the person properties. Student/Teacher table would be for their specific student/teacher properties, and the primary key would be the same joining them to Person.